# Popular post 'of the week'

Tags: popular-posts

I would like to know how can I make my widget get the popular post by week ?
 Right now it show only popular post since the beginning of the website.

here is my code :

// PopularPosts Widget

```
{
function PopularPosts(){
$widget_ops = array('description' => 'Shows the most commented posts.');
$control_ops = array('width' => 200, 'height' => 300);
parent::__construct(false,$name='[Voxis] Articles populaires',$widget_ops,$control_ops);
}
```

/* Displays the Widget in the front-end */

```
function widget($args, $instance){
extract($args);

$title = apply_filters('widget_title', empty($instance['title']) ? '' : $instance['title']);
$number_posts = $instance['number_posts'];
$categories = $instance['categories'];

echo $before_widget; 

if ( $title != '' )
    echo $before_title . $title . $after_title;

echo '
<div class="list">
    <ul>';
$args = array();
$args['posts_per_page'] = $number_posts;
$args['orderby'] = 'comment_count';
$args['order'] = 'DESC';
if(!empty($categories) )
    $args['category__in'] = $categories;
$query = new WP_Query($args);
while($query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); global $post; ?>
    <li>
        <a title="<?php the_title();?>" href="<?php the_permalink();?>">
            <figure>
                <?php if(has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>">
                        <img src="<?php echo aq_resize(wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) ), 42, 42, true); ?>" alt="<?php the_title();?>" />
                    </a>
                <?php } else { ?>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>">
                        <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() . '/img/missing_56.png';?>" alt="<?php the_title();?>" />
                    </a>
                <?php } ?>
            </figure>
            <p>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title();?></a> <br /> 
                <span> <?php _e('Le ', 'Voxis'); the_time("F d, Y");?>, <?php comments_popup_link(esc_html__('0 commentaires','Voxis'), esc_html__('1 commentaire','Voxis'), '% '.esc_html__('commentaires','Voxis')); ?> </span>
            </p>
        </a>
    </li>
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata();
echo '</ul>
</div>';

echo $after_widget;}
```

/*Saves the settings. */

```
function update($new_instance, $old_instance){
$instance =  array();
$instance['title'] = esc_attr($new_instance['title']);
$instance['number_posts'] = (int)$new_instance['number_posts'];
$instance['categories'] = $new_instance['categories'];

return $instance;}
```

/*Creates the form for the widget in the back-end. */

```
function form($instance){
//Defaults
$instance = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, array('number_posts'=> 5, 'title' => '', 'categories' => array() ) );

$title = esc_attr($instance['title']);
$number_posts = (int) $instance['number_posts'];
$categories = (array) $instance['categories'];

echo '<p><label for="' . $this->get_field_id('title') . '">' . 'Title: ' . '</label><input id="' . $this->get_field_id('title') . '" name="' . $this->get_field_name('title') . '" value="'. esc_textarea($title)  . '" /></p>';
echo '<p><label for="' . $this->get_field_id('number_posts') . '">' . 'Number of posts: ' . '</label><input id="' . $this->get_field_id('number_posts') . '" name="' . $this->get_field_name('number_posts') . '" value="'. esc_textarea($number_posts)  . '" /></p>';
$cats = get_categories('hide_empty=0');
?>
<p>
    <label>Categories to include: </label> <br />
    <?php foreach( $cats as $category ) { ?>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('categories'); ?>[]" value="<?php echo $category->cat_ID; ?>"  <?php if(in_array( $category->cat_ID, $categories ) ) echo 'checked="checked" '; ?> /> 
            <?php echo $category->cat_name; ?>
        </label> <br />
    <?php } ?>
</p> 
<?php } }
```

// end PopularPosts class

Thank you all for the Support...

Comment: Do order by date and comment count

Comment: look into this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-popular-posts/

Comment: I don't understand how your widget works currently, it's just listing posts, it doesn't involve popularity at all. Also there is unformatted code, can you edit your post and make sure all code is interpreted as code so it's clearer?

Comment: Thanks Shady i already use it and i m trying avoid it and use personal coded one this code above is fine just cant make it work by week!

Comment: Also how are you tracking popularity? What makes a post popular, page views?

Comment: i fixed the code. I think that the popularity is traked by most commented, between i dindt build this code :p.

Comment: So you actually want to know how to list the X posts that were most commented in the last week? It can be done but it will be an expensive query, and it is not trivial

Comment: ok then maybe i ll try find some find another new code !

Comment: Hi guy's I posted another threat here and need your help please
http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/176236/wordpress-popular-posts-by-week-code